# Colorbar doesn't respect limit values

Tags: python, plotly

I have this plot:

[image]

The values range from 0 to 1, but the colorbar extends above 1 and below 0. I want the colorbar to NOT show values out of the `[0, 1]` range. How can this be done?

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Contour(
        z=np.random.rand(10,10),
        x=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        y=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=1,
            size=0.25,
        ),
        colorbar=dict(
            tick0=0,
            dtick=1
        )
))
fig.show()
```

Comment: I don't have the data, so I can't check it at hand, but I can set the color scale specifically, which may solve the problem. See the official [reference](https://plotly.com/python/colorscales/).

Comment: @r-beginners You can use any random numbers, I've updated the question with a full-working example for you to try if you can.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It appears that when using `contours.coloring='fill'` (which is the default) the `zmin` and `zmax` are ignored (for some reason).  If `contours.coloring='heatmap'` then `zmin` and `zmax` are honored.  At this time I don't see a good work around, but here are some things that might be helpful...

If your okay with a gradient then `contours.coloring='heatmap'` with `zmin=0` and `zmax=1` might be acceptable:

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Contour(
        z=np.random.rand(10,10),
        x=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        y=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=1,
            size=0.25,
            coloring="heatmap",
        ),
        colorbar=dict(
            tick0=0,
            dtick=1,
        ),
        zmin=0,
        zmax=1
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Another solution might be to set up discrete end points for the `colorscale`:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Contour(
        z=np.random.rand(10,10),
        x=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        y=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=1,
            size=0.25,
        ),
        colorbar=dict(
            tick0=0,
            dtick=1
        ),
        colorscale=[
            [0, "rgb(180, 0, 0)"],
            [0.25, "rgb(180, 0, 0)"],

            [0.75, "rgb(0, 180, 180)"],
            [1, "rgb(0, 180, 180)"],
        ],
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Unfortunately the lines and fill do not align perfectly if you try to combine these two and have discrete coloring throughout:

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Contour(
        z=np.random.rand(10,10),
        x=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        y=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=1,
            size=0.25,
            coloring="heatmap",
        ),
        colorbar=dict(
            tick0=0,
            dtick=1,
        ),
        colorscale=[
            [0, "rgb(40, 40, 40)"],
            [0.25, "rgb(40, 40, 40)"],

            [0.25, "rgb(80, 80, 80)"],
            [0.5, "rgb(80, 80, 80)"],

            [0.5, "rgb(120, 120, 120)"],
            [0.75, "rgb(120, 120, 120)"],

            [0.75, "rgb(180, 180, 180)"],
            [1, "rgb(180, 180, 180)"],
        ],
        zmin=0,
        zmax=1,
))
fig.show()
```

[image]
...although I'll poke around some more to see if there's another argument that will help these align.

**UPDATE**:
Using a discrete color of white at 10% of each end will get us mostly there.  We also need to set the `outlinecolor` and `outlinewidth` to hide an unsightly border that shows up.

```
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Contour(
        z=np.random.rand(10,10),
        x=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        y=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=1,
            size=0.25,
        ),
        colorbar=dict(
            tick0=0,
            dtick=1,
            outlinewidth=2,
            outlinecolor="rgb(255, 255, 255)",
        ),
        colorscale=[
            [0, "rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
            [0.1, "rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
            [0.1, "rgb(180, 180, 0)"], #here is where you set your min color
            [0.9, "rgb(0, 0, 180)"], #here is where you set your max color
            [0.9, "rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
            [1, "rgb(255, 255, 255)"],
        ],
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: @jayveesa Excellent answer! Just wanted to say it...

Comment: The last update is exactly what I was looking for. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I tried it according to the official reference and saw it. I specified the lower and upper limits, respectively. The lower limit is red and the upper limit is blue.

```
import numpy as np
import plotly.graph_objects as go

fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Contour(
        z=np.random.rand(10,10),
        x=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        y=np.linspace(0,10,10),
        contours=dict(
            start=0,
            end=1,
            size=0.25,
        ),
    colorscale=[[0, "rgb(0,0,255)"],
                [1, "rgb(255,0,0)"]],
))
fig.show()
```

[image]

Comment: The issue is still there. The colorbar extends above 1 and below 0, which shouldn't happend given that 0 and 1 are the limit values.

Comment: As far as I can tell, there is no solution to this problem; wouldn't a gradient between two colors solve it?